# View pvclust tree with many nodes in R

Tags: r, plot, hierarchical-clustering, pvclust

Is there any way to view hierarchical tree with too many nodes (around 10000+)? Changing the text size is not a viable option to see the labels at all.  I tried converting to dendrogram and cut but the p-values disappear. I need to see the p-values as well.

[Currently it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aaGS.png)